# Variable not Defined, Function definition includes variable?

Tags: python

```
sequence = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


def caesar( original, variationShift):
    '''returns: a version of original created by replacing each letter with 
       the letter "variationShift" units later in the alphabet sequence.
       If variationShift is negative, replacing letter is found earlier in  
       alphabet.'''
    index = 0
    result = ''
    while index < len( original):
        lookFor = original[ index]
        foundAt = sequence.find( lookFor)
        if foundAt == -1:
            # untranslatable character
            result += lookFor
        else:
            result += sequence[ variationShift]  # negative indexes OK!

        index += 1
    return result

def encryptCaesar (original):
    caesar( original, foundAt - 3)
    return result

def decryptCaesar (original):
    caesar( original, (foundAt + 3) % len(sequence))
    return result
```

The variable `foundAt` is constantly being said to be undefined. Yet, it is defined in `caesar`. Is a variable undefined until the function is actually run once? Or during that run?

Comment: `foundAt` is a local variable within the `caesar` function. It's not visible outside the function.

Comment: `foundAt` is only defined within the scope of `caesar`.  It's not considered to exist anywhere else.  So, the question is, do you really need to use `foundAt` in those other methods?  It wouldn't make sense to me that a cipher needs to know that much at that level.

Comment: And even if there weren't a scope problem, you're using the variable in the argument to `caesar`, so you need it to have a value **before** it's set inside the function. What sense does that make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers explain about variable scope, but you have some more basic issues.  You are mixing where these variables are used. What you want to do is pass the shift. You don't know the `foundAt` location at the calling point, that is calculated in the loop.  The other issue is the return value.  You need to return the value from `caesar()`.  The code below does the standard caesar encryption and decryption.

```
sequence = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def caesar( original, variationShift):
    '''returns: a version of original created by replacing each letter with 
       the letter "variationShift" units later in the alphabet sequence.
       If variationShift is negative, replacing letter is found earlier in  
       alphabet.'''
    index = 0
    result = ''
    while index < len( original):
        lookFor = original[ index]
        foundAt = sequence.find( lookFor)
        if foundAt == -1:
            # untranslatable character
            result += lookFor
        else:
            result += sequence[ (foundAt + variationShift) % len(sequence)]
        index += 1
    return result

def encryptCaesar (original):
    return caesar( original, -3)

def decryptCaesar (original):
    return caesar( original, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the code inside the function definition is actually run until the function is executed.

Furthermore, variables defined inside a function are only valid inside *that function*.  To quote [A Guide to Python namespaces](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/):

> At any time there are a number of scopes in operation: the scope of the current function you’re in, the scope of the module and then the scope of the Python builtins. This nesting of scopes means that one function can’t access names inside another function.

`foundAt` is an example of a variable defined inside a function namespace (the namespace of `caesar`).  `sequence` is an example of a variable defined inside the module namespace.  So, you can access `sequence` inside `caesar` and other functions, but you cannot access `foundAt` outside of `caesar`.

If you want `foundAt` to be accessible inside `encryptCaesar` you need to pass it in as an argument, or declare it in a namespace that is a parent of `encryptCaesar` (the module namespace -- or, alternatively, you can define `encryptCaesar` inside `caesar` and access the variable defined in the parent function via a closure).  In most cases passing it in as an argument is what you wnat.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the scope of the function, `foundAt` is a local variable only found within the `caesar` function. To get around that, use `global` variables:

```
>>> def foo():
...     global oof
...     oof = 9
... 
>>> oof
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'oof' is not defined
>>> def boo():
...     global oof
...     oof+=1
... 
>>> global oof
>>> foo()
>>> oof
9
>>> boo()
>>> oof
10
>>>
```

### In your code:

```
sequence = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


def caesar( original, variationShift):
    global foundAt
    '''returns: a version of original created by replacing each letter with 
       the letter "variationShift" units later in the alphabet sequence.
       If variationShift is negative, replacing letter is found earlier in  
       alphabet.'''
    index = 0
    result = ''
    while index < len( original):
        lookFor = original[ index]
        foundAt = sequence.find( lookFor)
        if foundAt == -1:
            # untranslatable character
            result += lookFor
        else:
            result += sequence[ variationShift]  # negative indexes OK!

        index += 1
    return result

def encryptCaesar (original):
    global foundAt
    caesar( original, foundAt - 3)
    return result

def decryptCaesar (original):
    global foundAt
    caesar( original, (foundAt + 3) % len(sequence))
    return result
```